# Numpy slicing/indexing changes order of axis

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing, numpy-indexing

I was working on a code and noticed that numpy indexing and slicing doesn't work as I expected. For example,

```
x = np.random.randn(1,5,3,4)
y = x[0, :, :, [1,2]]
y.shape
```

I expected y.shape to be (5,3,2) but instead got (2,5,3). Does anyone know why the expected third axis is moved to the first axis?

Comment: This is a case of mixed basic and advanced indexing.   As documented, and previous SO, the slice dimensions are placed last..  A work around is to split off the first index `x[0][ :, :, [1,2]]`